# How commonplace is "skimming" of duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[What does the *= operator do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339864/what-does-the-operator-do) was marked as a duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

The question asked what the `*=` operator does in PHP.

Unfortunately, `*=` isn't mentioned in that question. It just looks like it might, since it's a list of operators.

This mistake was made by users with 4k, 6k, 9k, 11k, and 57k rep.

How can we avoid this happening?

Comment: I guess the answer to that one is "we can't". Reopen if it was closed incorrectly. Comment if it has a vote, but is not closed yet.

Comment: Meh - simply searching for that string on the post is not enough... Reading through that page there are several links to PHP docs which **do** reference that operator.

Comment: @Lix There are a huge amount of links on that page; do you suggest the OP clicks all of them?

Comment: @DannyBeckett Which is exactly why I think that particular approach to a common question duplicate closure is horrible. It's only ever convenient for those who vote to close.

Comment: Personally I think the linked question should be closed. I'm also in the "meh" camp, it's a poor question, because there's a PHP language manual-you don't *have* to search for the operator itself. To answer your question: you can't, if it's a mistake, then you're asking "how can we prevent mistakes". The recourse is flagging a mod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that commonplace, but botched closings do happen often (given the size of SO, this makes sense). Vote to reopen, or custom flag asking for the same. Leave a comment specifying that the post isn't a dupe, and add an entry for it in the PHP FAQ post.